# How do I refresh a function without the content being appended?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that displays an array. There's test button I created aiming to refresh the table but every time I click it, it appends another table below the existing table instead of just refreshing the current table. How can I make it refresh the current table only?

```js
function test() {
  var hst = document.getElementById("highscores");

  var highScores = [{
      name: "Maximillian",
      score: 1000
    },
    {
      name: "The second guy",
      score: 700
    },
    {
      name: "The newbie",
      score: 50
    },
  ];

  localStorage.setItem("highscores", JSON.stringify(highScores));

  var retrievedScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highscores"));

  for (var i = 0; i < retrievedScores.length; i++) {
    hst.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + retrievedScores[i].name + "</td><td>" + retrievedScores[i].score + "</td></tr>";
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="highscores">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Score</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick=test()>Test</button>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richjr93/7j4d5u2a/) if the snippet doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: The function uses `+=` to add to the innerHTML. Why wouldn't that append?

Comment: Empty the `innerHTML` before the loop. Better yet, put all the new table contents into a string, then assign the whole thing to `innerHTML` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Ok based on the comment by Barmar which is to empty the `innerHTML` before the loop, what I did was simply adding `hst.innerHTML = "";` right above the `for...` line and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).